# How to make Kurzgesagt style smoke (translucent moving circles that don't overlap)

Tags: mesh, 2d

I'm trying to replicate the smoke in this Kurzgesagt video scene using Blender (from seconds 0:07-0:12)

https://youtu.be/h6fcK_fRYaI?t=7

The smoke columns are basically different circles of a translucent material that move over time. Different smoke columns overlap in color, BUT the same smoke column doesn't overlap. How could I make a smoke column, that has different moving circles (all with a translucent material) but that are somehow joined and don't overlap?
Since they are different circles I don't know how to do it in a way that the materials don't overlap...
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Create a material combining two voronoi textures! Tune the circle size with the `Less than` value, also play with the Voronoi scale and the texture coordinate etc. Use the `clamp` to overlap circles.

Here is a simple plane with such a material:

[image]

Comment: You're good! :)